# JTable rendering JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a one column `JTable` to which I set a custom `TableCellRenderer` that return a custom `JPanel` in its `getTableCellRendererComponent` method.

The custom `JPanel` contains several `JTextField` and `JButton` and only one instance of the custom `JPanel` is created and in the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method I just set its `JTextField` values from data model object.

In order to make the `JTextFiel` editable and `JButton` clickable I had to set the `isCellEditable` method from `JTable` model to true as well as create a class implementing `TableCellEditor` with `isCellEditable` to true, and set the default cell editor of my `JTable` with it.

I would like to get the table selected row when clicking on some buttons of my custom `JPanel`, but it always returns me -1.  If I add a ListSelectionListener to the JTable it is even not calling the valueChanged method when clicking in a row.  If I remove the cell editor, it is working properly.  Why is the `ListSelectionListener` not working if a cell editor is added to the `JTable` and why do I need to provide a cell editor ?  The isCellEditable from `JTable` model not enough ?

Comment: not sure where is your issue, by default ListSelectionListener returns Renderers JComponent and XxxTableCellEditor too

Comment: If I add a ListSelectionListener to the JTable it is even not calling the valueChanged method unless I don't set a cell editor to the JTable.

Comment: please to see my post an answer here, is there the same issue, whats real your problem, everything depends of model_to_view, by default never to put any JComponents to the Model, but good example for your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSCCE for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class PanelInTable {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTable CompTable = null;
    private PanelTableModel CompModel = null;
    private JButton addButton = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception fail) {
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new PanelInTable().makeUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeUI() {
        CompTable = CreateCompTable();
        JScrollPane CompTableScrollpane = new JScrollPane(CompTable, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        JPanel bottomPanel = CreateBottomPanel();
        frame = new JFrame("Comp Table Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(CompTableScrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JTable CreateCompTable() {
        CompModel = new PanelTableModel();
        CompModel.addRow();
        JTable table = new JTable(CompModel);
        table.setRowHeight(new CompCellPanel().getPreferredSize().height);
        table.setTableHeader(null);
        PanelCellEditorRenderer PanelCellEditorRenderer = new PanelCellEditorRenderer();
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, PanelCellEditorRenderer);
        table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, PanelCellEditorRenderer);
        return table;
    }

    public JPanel CreateBottomPanel() {
        addButton = new JButton("Add Comp");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Object source = ae.getSource();
                if (source == addButton) {
                    CompModel.addRow();
                }
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.add(addButton);
        return panel;
    }
}

class PanelCellEditorRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private CompCellPanel renderer = new CompCellPanel();
    private CompCellPanel editor = new CompCellPanel();

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        renderer.setComp((Comp) value);
        return renderer;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        editor.setComp((Comp) value);
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return editor.getComp();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        return false;
    }
}

class PanelTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public void addRow() {
        super.addRow(new Object[]{new Comp(0, 0, "", "")});
    }
}

class Comp {

    public int type;
    public int relation;
    public String lower;
    public String upper;

    public Comp(int type, int relation, String lower, String upper) {
        this.type = type;
        this.relation = relation;
        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;
    }
}

class CompCellPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel labelWith = new JLabel("With ");
    private JComboBox typeCombo = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"height", "length", "volume"});
    private JComboBox relationCombo = new JComboBox(new Object[]{"above", "below", "between"});
    private JTextField lowerField = new JTextField();
    private JLabel labelAnd = new JLabel(" and ");
    private JTextField upperField = new JTextField();
    private JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");

    CompCellPanel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        relationCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                enableUpper(relationCombo.getSelectedIndex() == 2);
            }
        });
        enableUpper(false);
        removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTable table = (JTable) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTable.class, (Component) e.getSource());
                int row = table.getEditingRow();
                table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                ((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row);
            }
        });
        add(labelWith);
        add(typeCombo);
        add(relationCombo);
        add(lowerField);
        add(labelAnd);
        add(upperField);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(100));
        add(removeButton);
    }

    private void enableUpper(boolean enable) {
        labelAnd.setEnabled(enable);
        upperField.setEnabled(enable);
    }

    public void setComp(Comp Comp) {
        typeCombo.setSelectedIndex(Comp.type);
        relationCombo.setSelectedIndex(Comp.relation);
        lowerField.setText(Comp.lower);
        upperField.setText(Comp.upper);
        enableUpper(Comp.relation == 2);
    }

    public Comp getComp() {
        return new Comp(typeCombo.getSelectedIndex(), relationCombo.getSelectedIndex(), lowerField.getText(), upperField.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need your cell selection in your editor?

Isn't it enough that you know row and column you are currently editing?

If yes then just set them where you set your editor value.

```
@Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        renderer.setComp((Comp) value, row, column );
        return renderer;
    }
```