# JTable with JSpinner Enable/Disable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox, jspinner

I've got a 3 column JTable.  Column 2 is a checkbox which I want to enable/disable the JSpinner for that row.

I've got working how I want except for one thing -- The JSpinner doesn't actually look like its disabled (text and spinner buttons greyed out).   I'm not quite sure how to attain this.  I've tried forcibly calling setEnabled(false) on the JSpinner, but the table doesn't seem to redraw correctly.

Here is some code I've gotten working through other StackOverflow examples:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class SpinnerTable {
    public JComponent makeUI() {
        String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Spinner Enable", "Spinner" };
        final Object[][] data = { { "aaa", true, 1 }, { "bbb", true, 10 },
                { "ccc", true, 10 } };

        final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {

            @Override
            public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
                super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {

                if (column == 2)
                    return (Boolean) model.getValueAt(row, 1);

                return super.isCellEditable(row, column);
            }

        };

        table.setRowHeight(36);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        column.setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxCellRenderer());
        column.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxCellEditor());

        return new JScrollPane(table);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new SpinnerTable().makeUI());
        f.setSize(320, 240);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class SpinnerPanel extends JPanel {
    protected JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
            return new Dimension(40, d.height);
        }
    };

    public SpinnerPanel() {
        super();
        setOpaque(true);
        add(spinner);
    }
}

class ComboBoxCellRenderer extends SpinnerPanel implements TableCellRenderer {
    public ComboBoxCellRenderer() {
        super();
        setName("Table.cellRenderer");
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table
                .getBackground());
        if (value != null) {
            spinner.setValue(value);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

class ComboBoxCellEditor extends SpinnerPanel implements TableCellEditor {
    public ComboBoxCellEditor() {
        super();
        spinner.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                fireEditingStopped();

            }
        });
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                fireEditingStopped();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        this.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        spinner.setValue(value);
        return this;
    }

    // Copid from DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate
    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return spinner.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
        if (anEvent instanceof MouseEvent) {
            MouseEvent e = (MouseEvent) anEvent;
            return e.getID() != MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopCellEditing() {
        fireEditingStopped();
        return true;
    };

    transient protected ChangeEvent changeEvent = null;

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelCellEditing() {
        fireEditingCanceled();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        listenerList.add(CellEditorListener.class, l);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l) {
        listenerList.remove(CellEditorListener.class, l);
    }

    public CellEditorListener[] getCellEditorListeners() {
        return listenerList.getListeners(CellEditorListener.class);
    }

    protected void fireEditingStopped() {
        // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
        // those that are interested in this event
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == CellEditorListener.class) {
                // Lazily create the event:
                if (changeEvent == null)
                    changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
                ((CellEditorListener) listeners[i + 1])
                        .editingStopped(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void fireEditingCanceled() {
        // Guaranteed to return a non-null array
        Object[] listeners = listenerList.getListenerList();
        // Process the listeners last to first, notifying
        // those that are interested in this event
        for (int i = listeners.length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2) {
            if (listeners[i] == CellEditorListener.class) {
                // Lazily create the event:
                if (changeEvent == null)
                    changeEvent = new ChangeEvent(this);
                ((CellEditorListener) listeners[i + 1])
                        .editingCanceled(changeEvent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table does not know it should repaint the cell in column 2 when column 1 was modified. You can notify the table by firing an update manually. For example, extend model's `setValueAt()`:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    super.setValueAt(aValue, row, column);
    if (column == 1)
        fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
}
```

This will disable the editor and spinner will become not editable. If you need to actually disable the spinner visually, then, inside the renderer you can enable/disable the spinner based on `isCellEditable`, ie:

```
spinner.setEnabled(table.isCellEditable(row, column));
```

Note that in your current implementation you extend `JTable` to implement `isCellEditable` and `setValueAt`. These should really be part of the model.

Comment: fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row); not necassary, isn't in concern with DefaultTableModel, then this notifier is called twice

Comment: @dubdubdubdot move everything, every code lines from JTable to DefaultTableModel

Comment: put simple spinner to Renderer, JPanel is moreover, useless, or there is another option to put all JComponents to JPanel, [then there will be JTable with one column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15090127/714968)

Comment: @mKorbel `fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row)` can be replaced with `fireTableCellUpdated(row, 2)` to avoid dup call.

Comment: I't talking about DefaultTableModel notifier is called automatically, is implemented in API (correct me, am I wrong)

Comment: @mKorbel `DefaultTableModel.setValueAt()` calls `fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);` So it would trigger refresh only on the given cell.

Comment: :-) dirty hack, now I'm get it, isn't better to call setValueAt(getValueAt) for real refresh of rendered JComponents

Comment: @mKorbel I agree, `setValueAt(getValueAt)` is cleaner.