# Calculate value from Rows of JTable and show it in another row when press button save Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I need to show the result in Row of `JTable` by calculate the value of rows using MySQL. Recevied + PCU stored in Balance when the user click the save button. What will be the query?

`JTable` showing the records; save the record of the table.

[image: Picture of Jtable]

```
JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
Image img4= new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/save.png")).getImage();
btnSave.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img4));
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


        try{
            String query="insert into Detail (ID,Date,Received,PCU,CLR,Sole,Sale,Balance) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);

            pst.setString(1,textField.getText());
            pst.setString(2,textField_1.getText());
            pst.setString(3,textField_2.getText());
            pst.setString(4,textField_3.getText());
            pst.setString(5,textField_4.getText());
            pst.setString(6,textField_5.getText());
            pst.setString(7,textField_6.getText());
            pst.setInt(8, 2-3 );

            pst.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");
            pst.close();
            //rs.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        refreshTable();
    }
```

Comment: Your question is too broad; please focus own a single question; examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22142805/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513).

Comment: sir i want a query for that can you help?

Comment: your Example is perfect but I want to save the data in MYsql

Comment: When user enter data in Received and PCU it will add and show in Balance (Total)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Recevied + PCU stored in Balance when the user click the save button.

So do the calculation when you store data to the table.

First of all the Received and PCU should NOT be stored as Strings. They should be stored an int's.

So your code should be something like:

```
int receivedData = Integer.parseInt( textField_?.getText() );
int pcuData = Integer.parseInt( textField_?.getText() );

pst.setInt(?, receivedData);
pst.setInt(?, pcuData);
...
pst.setInt(8, receivedData + pcuData);
```

Also, use meaningful variable names. I have no idea what textField_1, 2, 3, 4, represent. Use names like received, pcu, clr etc so we know what you are taking about.

Comment: Sir, You are great , It helped me, Thank you so mUch ;)